# Elasticsearch Nest conditional sort

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to write an elasticsearch query which gets most recent top 100 from orders and sales, but my problem is orders have shipment_date. I want to use "shipment_date" for orders, "created_date" for sales to sort them. I couldn't find a way to do this, there are some solutions with script but they didn't work for me maybe because I am using elasticsearch version 6. Thank you

```
var response = client.Search<DataModel>(x => 
x.Index("order*,sale*").Type("")
.Query(q =>
q.Term(t => t.customerID, customerID) &&
q.DateRange(d => d
    .Field(f => f.created_date)
    .GreaterThanOrEquals(fromDate)
    .LessThanOrEquals(toDate)
    )
)
.From(0)
.Size(100)
.Sort(s => s.Field(f => f
.Field("created_date")
.Order(SortOrder.Descending)
))
);
```

Example documents:

Order:

```
"order_id": "8796",
"item_id": "69813",
"price": 50.25,
"quantity": 1,
"status": 3,
"shipment_date": "2018-01-04T16:01:24Z",
"order_date": "2018-01-03T21:19:04Z"
```

Sale:

```
"sale_id": "4032",
"order_id": "8796",
"created_date": "2018-01-09T18:23:11Z"
```

Comment: show us a sample elasticsearch document from your application

Comment: @dilsingi thanks for response, I added 2 example documents

Comment: I answered this over at: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-net-conditional-sort/120368/2?u=forloop